# Get full URL with hash to use as ReturnUrl

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, returnurl

I have such URL

```
localhost/Login/LogOn?ReturnUrl=/#&q=my%20search%20word&f=1//447044365|2//4
```

I need to get hash parameters to navigate in the application after authentication.

I try to catch it like this

```
<input name="returnUrl" value="<%= ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery %>" type="hidden" />
```

But result is

```
/Login/LogOn?ReturnUrl=/
```

I tried to take away "/#" in the URL, then I get whole URL. But I need to use this URL as it is.

Why was URL cutted?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The browser does not send the hash fragment to the server.  It used on the client-side only.  If you need it you will have to access it through client-side script.

Comment: Thanks! I have just added $("#returnUrl").val(location.hash); to place it in the input.

Comment: With client-side URL processing like this, be mindful of inject/hijack attacks. Make sure the consumer of this value is untrusting and validates it.