# Getting the full url of the current page with url hash on server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

I cant get the full url of the page that I am working on. This is the url that I want to get `http://localhost:54570/Shipment/ShipmentDetails.aspx?HawbBLNo=NEC00000004#BFT`The result is only `http://local/Shipment/ShipmentDetails.aspx?HawbBLNo=NEC00000004` on this code

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
    UpdateDetails();
    Response.Redirect(url);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Url Hash (#) from server side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317760/how-to-get-url-hash-from-server-side)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

there is no way to get hash content on server side because hash are never posted to the server

see this question for some tricks [How to get Url Hash (#) from server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317760/how-to-get-url-hash-from-server-side)

Answer (score 4):

> It's not possible to retrieve the #anchor from the server side in ASP.NET
>
> This is a client-side flag to tell the browser to move to a specific place within the page.

Please take a look at this same discussion

[Retrieving Anchor Link In URL for ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774136/retrieving-anchor-link-in-url-for-asp-net)

and

[Get full URL with hash to use as ReturnUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536560/get-full-url-with-hash-to-use-as-returnurl)